# Is there a good way to filter all the robots and domains they are on?

Tags: logging, web-crawlers

I have been working more on the bot filter for my website, but by no means is it complete.

So far I have the main ones:

Google,
Yahoo, 
MSN,
Baidu,
Amazon,
and a few others...

Right now, I am using a filter to compare the referral URL, existing domain, and known browsers vs. non-browser useragents.

Are there any other good techniques to detect if the hit is coming from a bot or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any other good techniques to
>   detect if the hit is coming from a bot
>   or not?

It depends upon which variety of bot you're hunting - here are a few tips for isolating malicious bots:

- Look for hits on non-existent (or
  restricted access) administrative
  scripts, e-mail scripts, et cetera
- Look for nearly-instantaneous
  retrieval of your site content
- Look for repeated hits on your feeds
  (particularly if you know that your
  content is being used on scraper
  sites)

You might also check out [user-agent.org](http://www.user-agents.org/) for some of the more obscure search bot agents you can expect to see and review the [Where can I find a list of search engine crawler user agents and their domain names?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-search-engine-crawler-user-agents-and-their-domain-nam/) thread started by Dev a few days ago.